# Access minikube from inside docker/docker-compose on Linux

Tags: docker, kubernetes, curl, minikube

### The setup:

I have a minikube setup and a docker-compose setup side by side running. This way I can easily develop my application within docker/docker-compose and run other services within minikube. I'm working on Linux (Ubuntu).

### The problem:

I'd like to access the minikube API within a docker container running inside docker-compose with cURL.

### What I've tried:

- Accessing minikube with the proxy setup: `curl http://localhost:8080/api` (when using the kubectl proxy `kubectl proxy --port=8080`) but that ofcourse won't work because localhost is the container's localhost. This leads to `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`
- Accessing minikube via the docker internal host: `curl http://host.docker.internal:8080/api`. This also leads to `curl: (7) Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 8080: Connection refused`.
- Accessing minikube through the api/credentials found from the script below:

```
APISERVER=$(kubectl config view --minify | grep server | cut -f 2- -d ":" | tr -d " ")
SECRET_NAME=$(kubectl get secrets | grep ^default | cut -f1 -d ' ')
TOKEN=$(kubectl describe secret $SECRET_NAME | grep -E '^token' | cut -f2 -d':' | tr -d " ")

curl $APISERVER/api --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
```

But that all fails.

I've also added this to my docker-compose.yml file:

```
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

It all works fine when I try the above commands outside the docker container.
How do I access minikube from inside a docker container?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you wrap you development also using kubernetes manifests and deploy your service inside cluster. Just one time setup and then you can test multiple times instead of docker-compose way for dev setup.

Having said that, I tried your above setup (But I tried in mac, minikube and docker for mac). The solution that worked was doing exactly these:

1. Add `extra_hosts` to docker-compose:

> ```
> version: "3.9"
> services:
>   busy1:
>     image: progrium/busybox
>     command: sleep 3600
>     extra_hosts:
>      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
> ```

2. Run a hello-world sample and expose it using service in minikube (this is similar to creating deployment and service manifests)

> ```
> minikube kubectl -- create deployment node-hello --image=gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0 --port=8080 
> minikube kubectl -- expose deployment node-hello --port=8080
> ```

3. Run minikube with flag `--disable-filter=true` to overcome `forbidden` as response.

> `minikube kubectl -- proxy --disable-filter=true --port=8080`

4. Use `host.docker.internal` from within the container running in docker to access host

> ```
> curl http://host.docker.internal:8080/api/  
> {
>   "kind": "APIVersions",
>   "versions": [
>     "v1"
>   ],
>   "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
>     {
>       "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
>       "serverAddress": "192.168.49.2:8443"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

So basically flow is, container -> host.docker.internal -> kubectl proxy -> kubernetes service -> kubectl deployment

It totally depends on your kubernetes service configuration so that proxy will work fine. But like I said before, develop with kubernetes first mode and so that you can focus in logic and business functionality than worrying about network complexity. And all these varies with docker version, platform (linux, mac, windows etc), service configuration (or ingress) etc, bridge or overlay or host network used. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this still won't work for me. I'm aware that my development environment is not how it should be. Are you available to teach me how to properly setup a K8S development environment?

Comment: What did work is setting the network_mode to "host" in the docker-compose file. In that case I was able to call the proxy with from localhost.

Comment: Ok got it, In docker for Mac “network_mode” doesn’t seem to be working.

Comment: Btw regarding Dev setup. I meant you will have write kubernetes manifests around your image, based how your code is organised and you can easily rollout new image changes within the cluster rather than running it via separate docker container.

Comment: That sounds great but so far I’ve not found any good alternative to running inside docker locally for fast development cycles. Just change the code (php in this case) and hit refresh. Done. Tools like Skaffold come close but I have to work outside docker for it to work and I like having all the tools inside a container. Maybe I’m missing something?